# What fraction of multivariate polynomials with bounded individual degrees are irreducible?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, linear-algebra, polynomials, algebraic-curves, finite-fields

How many polynomials in $\mathbb{F}_p[x_1, \dots, x_m]$ with degree at most $d-1$ in each variable $x_i$ are irreducible?

Here $m$ and $d$ are positive integers, $p$ is a prime, and $\mathbb{F}_p$ is the field with $p$ elements.

Even if no closed form solution is known, I'd still be interested in hearing about asymptotic results (what's known for large $p$ or $m$) or lower bounds that say something about how the number of such irreducible polynomials compares to $q^{d^m}$, the total number of polynomials satisfying the degree condition.

Comment: Carlitz shows in https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ijm/1255644947 that almost all polynomials in $\mathbb{F}_q[x_1,\dots,x_m]$ of total degree $d$ are irreducible. Presumably a similar argument applies to polynomials of degree at most $d-1$ in each variable.